# Regex that validates for everything except particular extension names

Tags: regex, wildfly

I'm trying to get this regex to work so that `wildfly` server redirects all requests that do not include certain extensions to index.html

```
regex['^[^.]+$|\.(?!(js|css|svg|ico|jpg|html)$)([^.]+$)'] -> rewrite['/index.html']
```

The problem is that now anything with a double extension e.g. `.min.css` or `.min.js` will make the regular expression fail.

I have tried the following but it did not work:

```
regex['^[^.]+$|\.(?!(js|css|svg|ico|jpg|html|min\.css|min\.js)$)([^.]+$)'] -> rewrite['/index.html']
```

Any help and direction is much appreciated

Comment: What's the string you are matching against? Just the Filename? Or is it the request path? Could it include a query string? Also, is it necessary to match the entire input in order to be considered a successful match?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under the following assumptions

- the input is a URL path
- the query string is **not** part of the input
- partial matches don't count, the full input must be matched,

I'd go for

```
^(.*\.(?!js|css|svg|ico|jpg|html))?[^.]*$
```

How it works:

1. The greedy star `.*` immediately advances to the end of the string.
2. The dot `\.` backtracks to the first dot from the end of the string.
3. The look-ahead forbids certain file extensions.
4. The entire front part of the expression is optional, so we can match strings that don't contain a dot.
5. The `[^.]*$` matches the remainder of the string (the allowed file extension) in order to achieve an overall match.